# Finding noise frequency intervals in spectral analysis MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signals, fft, noise

I have a signal that has been distorted by narrowband noise.

A zoomed in image of it's spectral analysis:

[image: A zoomed in image of it's spectral analysis:]

I know that frequencies intervals, that I coloured in yellow are noise and the ones I coloured in green are the original signal.

[image: Coloured spectral analysis]

I could design filters just by hardcoding interval values from what I see, but I would like to automate the process and make an algorithm finding the noise intervals automatically.

Could you please suggest an approach (or maybe a function) that would be suitable here?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pwelch(x)` a command of matlabs dsp (digital signal processing) toolbox.

This function is specialized to differ between noise and signal.

Comment: Can you please provide an example on how to use the function you mention in this case and maybe a link to the documentation?

Comment: I have tried to use the aforementioned function with my signal, but the results are really similar to the one I get when I use fft for spectral analysis.

[Image of the result](https://i.imgur.com/9wFe2aw.png)

Is there anything I am missing?